# Why does my Fedora/Ubuntu frequently hang after suspending?

Tags: freeze

Sometimes, when I let my pc goes to hybernation due to a timeout, it freezes upon login. All apps close, nothing can be opened, my files are not listed and some app icons are not showing. I always have to force a shutdown.

```
Here is some more info:
dredre@fedora:~$ dmesg
[    0.000000] microcode: updated early: 0x429 -> 0x430, date = 2023-06-07
[    0.000000] Linux version 6.6.9-200.fc39.x86_64 (mockbuild@40899ab643a34e108460506c3edafa2d) (gcc (GCC) 13.2.1 20231205 (Red Hat 13.2.1-6), GNU ld version 2.40-13.fc39) #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jan  1 20:05:54 UTC 2024
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,gpt2)/vmlinuz-6.6.9-200.fc39.x86_64 root=UUID=c36a18fa-9ee8-4597-a529-b00b6b92a12a ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb quiet
[    0.000000] x86/split lock detection: #AC: crashing the kernel on kernel split_locks and warning on user-space split_locks
[    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009efff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000008c431fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000008c432000-0x0000000091b2efff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000091b2f000-0x000000009272efff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000009272f000-0x00000000927fefff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000927ff000-0x00000000927fffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000092800000-0x0000000096ffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000097a00000-0x0000000097bfffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000098400000-0x00000000a07fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c0000000-0x00000000cfffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed20000-0x00000000fed7ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000045f7fffff] usable
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] APIC: Static calls initialized
[    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.7 by Lenovo
[    0.000000] efi: ACPI=0x927fe000 ACPI 2.0=0x927fe014 TPMFinalLog=0x926ae000 SMBIOS=0x8e8af000 SMBIOS 3.0=0x8e8a2000 MEMATTR=0x8851f018 ESRT=0x8852c998 MOKvar=0x8c9da000 RNG=0x927fd018 TPMEventLog=0x6b025018 
[    0.000000] random: crng init done
[    0.000000] efi: Remove mem77: MMIO range=[0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] (256MB) from e820 map
[    0.000000] e820: remove [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] secureboot: Secure boot disabled
[    0.000000] SMBIOS 3.4.0 present.
[    0.000000] DMI: LENOVO 21E6CTO1WW/21E6CTO1WW, BIOS R1SET49W(1.20) 04/13/2023
[    0.000000] tsc: Detected 2500.000 MHz processor
[    0.000000] tsc: Detected 2496.000 MHz TSC
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Does it actually freeze, or is it simply busy reading from swap?

Comment: Hey! This is the output of 'free -h':  total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15Gi       4.4Gi       8.0Gi       1.0Gi       4.2Gi        10Gi
Swap:          8.0Gi          0B       8.0Gi. It seems I have enough memory, so maybe it has to do with the release of memory/processes,... Of course I can not see what happens during the freeze. (In fact I can move my cursor, etc but not much more.)

Comment: When you hibernate you write memory to swap and turn off everything. When you boot again it reads from swap back into memory. This may take some time. Let your computer sit for five-ten minutes in frozen state and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to see what happens, in the meantime I made a larger swap file, because I found that the swap partition should be at least as big as the RAM (which is 16G): swapon --show
NAME                      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/zram0                partition   8G   0B  100
/swapfile_subvol/swapfile file       16G   0B   -2

Comment: Are you using Fedora? Ubuntu? Both? Is this multi-boot? Do both OS share the same swap file?What do you mean by "force a shutdown"?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where the screen didn't freeze, but just didn't turn on. Updating the kernel (from 6.0.* to 6.2.0) solved it.

Check for error messages when it boots: I get

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x0000000005) is beyond end of object ...
```

(even after updating the kernel). This may help find the problem.

Regarding the swap, zero swap should be enough with 16 GB RAM (or maybe not), but I am somewhat sure that wasn't the problem. (I've heard that swap should be equal to RAM for 8G, and twice for less.)

Lastly, check if your device features on [the "Ubuntu Certified Hardware" list](https://ubuntu.com/certified/laptops). I found that my laptop was compatible with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but not 22.04, and till I updated the kernel, it worked.